# Localization does not commute with arbitrary intersection of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

So I proved that localization commutes with finite intersection of ideals,but at the same time I realised that we cannot generalize the proof to arbitrary intersection. So I tried coming up with an example and here it is.

$R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I_n=n \mathbb{Z}$ and $S= \mathbb{Z} \setminus 0 $. Then $$I=\bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty} I_n= \{0\}$$ and hence $S^{-1} I=0$

On the other hand $1=\frac{n}{n} \in S^{-1}(n \mathbb{Z})$ and hence I conclude that $\bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty} S^{-1} I_n$ contains a non-zero element.

Hence $$S^{-1} (\bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty} I_n) \neq \bigcap_{n=2}^{\infty}S^{-1}I_n$$

Is this example correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct